Is there a manual for the digelec LabPro logic programmer?
I have a digelec logic programmer, Model LabPro that was made by Advanced Micro Devices. I really need the manual to be able to use the device.
Searched the Internet for the documentation, could not find anything. Convinced that some online logic programmer might have a copy stored away.
